# Use local network for DB connection

Tags: php, mysql, networking, debian, proxmox

We have a dedicated server with proxmox on OVH. The idea is to connect the containers locally but also trough internet. So far I have 2 containers.

I added a bridge network for local IP and that is working since I am able to ping the containers from each other. 
Also added `bind-address=192.168.1.3` to my.cnf.

1 container is running apache + php 7.2 (192.168.1.3)

The other container is running MySQL. (192.168.1.2)

---

### Problem

My MySQL keeps saying `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out`

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Configuration for database connection
 *
 */

$host       = "192.168.1.2";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "root";
$dbname     = "test";
$dsn        = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
$options    = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
              );

try 
{
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $username, $password, $options);
    $sql = file_get_contents("data/init.sql");
    $connection->exec($sql);

    echo "Database and table users created successfully.";
}

catch(PDOException $error)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
}
```

From my understanding the code is correct so it must be something with my mysql configuration.
I'm sure that is something really simple but I'm losing to much time with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around for a while. Found out that I had to create a new user and grant permissions to it

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Also on my server config `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.conf` I had to **comment** the

```
bind-address  = 192.168.1.3
```

into

```
#bind-address  = 192.168.1.3
```

Then restart mysql server and change my mysql details on my php code with username 'monty' and password 'some_pass'

Answer (score 1):

Try to `telnet 192.168.1.2 3306` from the Apache, PHP container. Can you connect?

Ensure the listening port for MySQL is 3306, if other then adjust the PHP code accordingly. Also ensure that `iptables` is not blocking any incoming connections. Also ensure you have correct permissions for the `root` and any other users you need to have permissions from other hosts.

Also, please check when making any config changes to MySQL, that you restart the service.

Comment: Good test, but I think the they said MySQL is running on `192.168.1.2`

Comment: Yep .. connection timed out. But is weird since I allowed this specific IP to connect to 3306 same with icmp for ping which is working

Comment: Is there anything else that i'm missing on mysql settings?

Comment: can you try `nmap -sV -p 3306 192.168.1.2`? Seems that MySQL is not listening on port `3306`

Comment: ```
root@lampserver:/# nmap -sV -p 3306 192.168.1.2

Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-03-14 16:37 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.2
Host is up (0.000055s latency).
PORT     STATE    SERVICE VERSION
3306/tcp filtered mysql
MAC Address: 8E:F7:5A:62:FA:FA (Unknown)

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.44 seconds
```

Comment: `3306/tcp filtered` - presumably, the host is behind some sort of firewall. Here, the packet is simply dropped and you receive no response (not even a RST). Its definitely a MySQL config issue or a firewall such as `iptables`, more likely the former. Please ensure that MySQL allows remote connections and that you restart the service after all config changes. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, the firewall is open both TCP and UDP. On mySQL side I added bind-address=192.168.1.3 aswell idk if i'm missing more settings on mysql config